# Django rest_framework.views how to skip database connection for simple rest API

Tags: python, sql, django, django-rest-framework, backend

Is there a way to disable default behaviour of django rest framework so that it don't lookup backend database? In my project I have few simple API's which don't need database. But behind the scene Django try to connect with database which adds extra milli seconds in response time.

Note that I have CONN_MAX_AGE in my settings so in best case I won't see traces of MySQLdb:Connect but it would still do other-SQL because of its default behaviour.

I hope if somebody already have faced this problem and knows a solution.For more insight I have also pasted my trace of New Relic report of my simple API.

```
from rest_framework.views import View
class ServerStatusTestView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return HttpResponse('Some Response')
```

- MySQLdb:Connect ==> 65 ms
- WSGI/Response   ==> 21.1ms
- other - SQL     ==> 11.3ms
- django.core.urlresolvers:RegexURLResolver.resolve ==> .8ms
- django.http.response:HttpResponse.close ==> .5ms
- django.middleware.csrf:CsrfViewMiddleware.process_view ==>.5ms
- ServerStatusTestView  ===> .2ms
- django.middleware.common:CommonMiddleware.process_request ==> .1

**Edit-1 Addition>>** I just noticed that might be happening due to the remote "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware" where Django is trying to save the default session in database. which I added for django admin forms. So I think I might need to add some Middleware to bypass it for my simple API's, but I am still looking for an appropriate thing just like some decorator which I add at the top of my simple view and it doesn't test session. So still looking for recommendations!

**Edit-2 Addition>>** My thinking about session Middleware was wrong because I am using simple View not (ApiView), just for the sake of confirmation I disabled all of Middleware to see the impact, but a simple request still establish a connection with database. More interesting thing is that I have 2 more databases in my settings and my master database also get connection from the other databases when I load test my simple API Call. ( I checked my directly from MySql via "show processlist" command while the load test was running)

Comment: I take it you do not with to implement a test-only settings.py which has no mysql connection defined?

Comment: Yes, I am testing this in production, however I just saw that it might be the default session behaviour of the Django due to which it is happening, I am also going to edit my parent post.

Answer (score 2):

step1. implement custom database backend and raise exception on db intialization

```
from django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2 import base   

class DatabaseWrapper(base.DatabaseWrapper):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       raise RuntimeError('db access restricted')
```

step2. look at traceback and determine who want db

sorry for my poor English

Comment: I did this and now its becoming very obvious that this is django's fixed default behaviour where it tries to reset all the connections before returning the response. Follow the link to see the stack trace. Just for info I am using MySql.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/132BRlBjNTdfGZCFR2HJqwti95bndPllcHJ-_Q2DLShs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: you right...  seems like Django initiate db connection on reset_queries signal without care it is needed or not...
you can try disconnect default reset_queries signal, and clear queries log manually  or more simply do not use DEBUG=True )

Comment: in yours trace on signal `reset_queries` django do log cleanup where initialize db connection if it was not initialized before.
You must try to disconnect this signal, but probably you will have memory leak by growing queries logs

Comment: Thank you estin, your hints are really helpful. Yes, we tried that too but memory-leaks are very crucial the CPU ate-up  100% memory. For now the best way I have found is to at-least leave the "default" database as empty {} and disable all the operations which need database connections for the APIs i.e Authentication, Session etc, because in my case I don't need built-in authentication